# Sitecore-Download of specified resource failed

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7

I have created a custom button to generate urls of items(using LinkManager) under home item and write it to a temp.js file and then show a  SheerResponse.Alert() to user about succes of file generation.

This works fine in Firefox and Chrome.However in I.E when i debug the code the code gets executed correctly and file gets generated however instead of a sucess alert i see the below :

[image]

Any Suggestions will be helpfull.

```
string output = FormatOutput(urls);
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(output))
                    {
                        if (File.Exists(filepath))
                        {
                            File.Delete(filepath);
                        }
                        File.WriteAllText(filepath, output);
                       SheerResponse.Alert(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[Constants.FileDownloadedMessage]);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        SheerResponse.Alert(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[Constants.ContentMessage]);
                    }
```

Here urls is a list of string which I am formatting before I write to a file,I am getting list of urls for all item under home based on the value of a Checkbox field.

Comment: Can you please post your code, so we can try to find what's wrong?

Comment: I suspect this has something to do with the way you stream the file to the browser. What kind of stream method are you using?

Comment: @KevinBrechbühl Please find the code that i am using.

Comment: @Younes Please find the code that i am using